# sorting by different columns in a sequence or sorting by multiple columns at once

Tags: sort

What is the difference between `sort -t' ' -k1,1n -k2,2n` and `sort -t' ' -k1,2n`?

Could you give examples?

I've tried:

```
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage 
my age 1
my age 100
my age 2
my age 200
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort -k2,3
my age 1
my age 100
my age 2
my age 200
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort -k2,2 -k3,3
my age 1
my age 100
my age 2
my age 200
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort -k2,2 -k3,3n
my age 1
my age 2
my age 100
my age 200
```

I think `sort -k2,3` sorts 'age 1', 'age 100', ... and `sort -k2,2 -k3,3` sorts 'age', 'age',... then '1', '100', .... Since they all treat columns as strings they produce the same outcome.

But `sort -k2,2 -k3,3n` produces different outcome because it treats column 3 as numbers.

But then:

```
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort -k2,3n
my age 1
my age 100
my age 2
my age 200
```

which is strange. Found out the reason is because column 2 is not numbers.

```
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort --debug -k2,3n
sort: using ‘en_AU.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
my age 1
   ^ no match for key
________
my age 100
   ^ no match for key
__________
my age 2
   ^ no match for key
________
my age 200
   ^ no match for key
__________
```

Thanks.

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly with details of the research you have done to find an answer.

Comment: @24601 yep i edited the question thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see what is happening by `--debug` flag.

`sort -k2,3` indeed sorts 'age 1', 'age 100',...

```
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort --debug -t' ' -k2,3
sort: using ‘en_AU.UTF-8’ sorting rules
my age 1
   _____
________
my age 100
   _______
__________
my age 2
   _____
________
my age 200
   _______
__________
```

`sort -k2,2 -k3,3` sorts by 'age',... then '1', '100', ...

```
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort --debug -t' ' -k2,2 -k3,3
sort: using ‘en_AU.UTF-8’ sorting rules
my age 1
   ___
       _
________
my age 100
   ___
       ___
__________
my age 2
   ___
       _
________
my age 200
   ___
       ___
__________
```

Lastly

```
logan@logan-mainPC:~/my-test/learn-sort$ cat myage | sort --debug -t' ' -k2,2 -k3,3n
sort: using ‘en_AU.UTF-8’ sorting rules
my age 1
   ___
       _
________
my age 2
   ___
       _
________
my age 100
   ___
       ___
__________
my age 200
   ___
       ___
__________
```

treats third column as numbers.